# Firefox addon to select saved passwords

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Does anyone know about the addon to firefox that creates a button which lets me select saved usernames for current website and after selecting one it fills the login form?

I was using it but after reinstall of my computer I can't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The one that I'm aware of and use constantly is [LastPass](http://www.lastpass.com).

It is able to maintain multiple logins per domain, you can also link domains to use the same login.

It is also able to do form fills with multiple profiles, 2-factor authentication at lots more.

Comment: well, that`s not the one I meant but looks good to so I`ll give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: Also worth noting that LastPass which i also use has an android app available at a minimal cost which i've found invaluable on my tablet and smartphone

Comment: Indeed, and an iOS one too. It also has tools for exporting your data, one time passwords for use in Internet Cafe's and more. Recommended by many security professionals.